# Fast replacement of XML node values

Tags: java, xml, regex, xslt

I have a bunch of XML documents which contain personal information that I need to replace with fake data. The Person node contains the following elements:

- uuid - required, should not be touched.
- firstName - optional
- lastName - optional
- address - optional
- personID - required

A person may appear many times, in which case the same fake data should be used, i.e. if two Person nodes have the same personID, they should both recieve the same fake ID.

I have implemented some Java code that builds a DOM tree from the XML string and replaces the nodes before writing it back to a string. This works fine, but since I have so many documents I was wondering if there is a faster approach. Maybe through regular expressions or XSLT or something?

Here is an example document:

```xml
<ADocument>
  <Stuff>
    ...
  </Stuff>
  <OtherStuff>
    ...
  </OtherStuff>
  <Person>
    <uuid>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</uuid>
    <firstName>Some</firstName>
    <lastName>Person</lastName>
    <personID>111111111111</personID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <uuid>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</uuid>
    <firstName>Another Person</firstName>
    <address>Main St. 2</address>
    <personID>222222222222</personID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <uuid>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</uuid>
    <firstName>Some</firstName>
    <lastName>Person</lastName>
    <personID>111111111111</personID>
  </Person>
  <MoreStuff>
    ...
  </MoreStuff>
</ADocument>
```

And this is my current implementation:

```java
public String replaceWithFalseData(String xmlInstance) {
    Document dom = toDOM(xmlInstance);

    XPathExpression xPathExpression = XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression("//Person");
    List<Node> nodeList = xPathExpression.evaluateAsNodeList(dom);

    for(Node personNode : nodeList) {
        Map<String, Node> childNodes = getChildNodes(personNode);
        String personID = childNodes.get("personID").getTextContent();
        // Retrieve a cached fake person using the ID, or create a new one if none exists.
        Person fakePerson = getFakePerson(personID);

        setIfExists(childNodes.get("firstName"), fakePerson.getFirstName());
        setIfExists(childNodes.get("lastName"), fakePerson.getLastName());
        setIfExists(childNodes.get("address"), fakePerson.getAddress());
        setIfExists(childNodes.get("personID"), fakePerson.getPersonID());
    }

    return toString(dom);
}

public Map<String, Node> getChildNodes(Node parent) {
    Map<String, Node> childNodes = new HashMap<String, Node>();
    for(Node child = parent.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
        if(child.getLocalName() != null) {
            childNodes.put(child.getLocalName(), child);
        }
    }
    return childNodes;
}

public void setIfExists(Node node, String value) {
    if(node != null) {
        node.setTextContent(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: By "fast" you mean more performant or more elegant?

Comment: What are the rules for creating fake firstName, lastName, address and personId attributes?

Comment: @DioF more performant

Comment: @BenL for names and address, just any arbitrary string - for personID, a 12 character long string of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who contributed! I ran a performance test on a set of 2000 XML documents using my DOM implementation, Sergej's StAX implementation and Ben's XSLT implementation as well as another implementation of my own, using regular expressions. The results came out as follows:

- DOM: 23,93s
- StAX: 20,37s
- XSLT: 83,52s
- Regex: 7,83s

And here is the winner:

```java
public String replaceWithFalseData(String xmlInstance) {
    Pattern personPattern = Pattern.compile("<Person>.*?</Person>", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher personMatcher = personPattern.matcher(xmlInstance);
    StringBuffer xmlBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while(personMatcher.find()) {
        String personXml = personMatcher.group();

        Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("<personID>(.*)</personID>");
        Matcher idMatcher = idPattern.matcher(personXml);
        idMatcher.find();
        String id = idMatcher.group(1);
        Person fakePerson = getFakePerson(id);

        personXml = personXml.replaceFirst("<firstName>.*</firstName>",
                "<firstName>" + fakePerson.getFirstName() + "</firstName>");

        personXml = personXml.replaceFirst("<lastName>.*</lastName>",
                "<lastName>" + fakePerson.getLastName() + "</lastName>");

        personXml = personXml.replaceFirst("<address>.*</address>",
                "<address>" + fakePerson.getAddress() + "</address>");

        personXml = personXml.replaceFirst("<personID>.*</personID>",
                "<personID>" + fakePerson.getPersonID() + "</personID>");

        personMatcher.appendReplacement(xmlBuffer, personXml);
    }

    personMatcher.appendTail(xmlBuffer);
    return xmlBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: This might be fast, but regex-based solutions aren't reliable. Jeff Atwood explains why: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ (HTML or XML, doesn't matter)

Answer (score 2):

You are using DOM based API. Faster replacement can be achieved with **Streaming API for XML (StAX)** which in many cases, can outperform the DOM-based API:
  [StAX versus DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html)

DOM API occupies more memory than StAX, which can degrade performance, but is easier to use than StAX API.

Working solution for your example - tested on 150 MB xml file, replaced in 10 sec:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;


public class ReplaceXmlWithFakeUser
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException
  {
    XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader eventReader = inFactory.createXMLEventReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\persons.xml")));
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventWriter writer = factory.createXMLEventWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\fakePersons.xml")));
    XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
    while (eventReader.hasNext())
    {
      XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

      if (event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&
        event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equals("Person"))
      {
        //write Person startElement:
        writer.add(event);


        /*
        STEP 1:
        personId is at the end of Person element. Cannot overwrite firstName and address element with fake data yet. Must call getFakePerson() first.
        Iterate till you read Person END element and just remember all events within person element which we will overwrite with fake data in step 2.
         */
        Person fakePerson=null;

        List<XMLEvent> eventsWithinPersonElement = new ArrayList<XMLEvent>();

        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
        while(!(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT && event.asEndElement().getName().toString().equals("Person")))
        {

          eventsWithinPersonElement.add(event);

          if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&
              event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equals("personID"))
          {
            XMLEvent personIDContentEvent = eventReader.nextEvent();

            String personId = personIDContentEvent.asCharacters().toString();
            fakePerson = getFakePerson(personId);

            eventsWithinPersonElement.add(personIDContentEvent);
          }

          event = eventReader.nextEvent();
        }
        XMLEvent personEndElement=event;


        //STEP 2:
        for (Iterator<XMLEvent> eventWithinPersonElementIterator = eventsWithinPersonElement.iterator(); eventWithinPersonElementIterator.hasNext(); )
        {
          XMLEvent eventWithinPersonElement = eventWithinPersonElementIterator.next();

          writer.add(eventWithinPersonElement);

          if(eventWithinPersonElement.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&
              eventWithinPersonElement.asStartElement().getName().toString().equals("personID"))
          {
            writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.personId));

            //skip personId event
            eventWithinPersonElementIterator.next();
          }
          if(eventWithinPersonElement.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&
              eventWithinPersonElement.asStartElement().getName().toString().equals("firstName"))
          {
            writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.firstName));

            //skip real firstName
            eventWithinPersonElementIterator.next();
          }
          if(eventWithinPersonElement.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&
              eventWithinPersonElement.asStartElement().getName().toString().equals("lastName"))
          {
            writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.lastName));

            //skip real firstName
            eventWithinPersonElementIterator.next();
          }
          else if(eventWithinPersonElement.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&
              eventWithinPersonElement.asStartElement().getName().toString().equals("address"))
          {
            writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.address));

            //skip real address
            eventWithinPersonElementIterator.next();

          }
        }

        writer.add(personEndElement);
      }
      else
      {
        writer.add(event);
      }
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  private static Person getFakePerson(String personId)
  {
    //create simple fake user...

    Person fakePerson = new Person();
    fakePerson.personId = personId;
    fakePerson.firstName = "fake first name: " + Math.random();
    fakePerson.lastName = "fake last name: " + Math.random();
    fakePerson.address = "fake address: " + Math.random();

    return fakePerson;
  }

  static class Person
  {
    String personId;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String address;

  }
}
```

Use `persons.xml` as input:

```
<ADocument>
    <Stuff>
        <StuffA></StuffA>
    </Stuff>
    <OtherStuff>
        <OtherStuff>
            <ABC>yada yada</ABC>
        </OtherStuff>
    </OtherStuff>

    <Person>
        <uuid>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</uuid>
        <firstName>Some</firstName>
        <lastName>Person</lastName>
        <personID>111111111111</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</uuid>
        <firstName>Another Person</firstName>
        <address>Main St. 2</address>
        <personID>222222222222</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</uuid>
        <firstName>Some</firstName>
        <lastName>Person</lastName>
        <personID>111111111111</personID>
    </Person>

    <MoreStuff>
        <foo></foo>
        <foo>fooo</foo>
        <foo><bar></bar></foo>
        <foo>
            <bar></bar>
            <bar/>
            <bar>bb</bar>
        </foo>
        <bar/>
    </MoreStuff>

</ADocument>
```

Producing this `fakePersons.xml` result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ADocument>
    <Stuff>
        <StuffA></StuffA>
    </Stuff>
    <OtherStuff>
        <OtherStuff>
            <ABC>yada yada</ABC>
        </OtherStuff>
    </OtherStuff>

    <Person>
        <uuid>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</uuid>
        <firstName>fake first name: 0.9518514637129984</firstName>
        <lastName>fake last name: 0.3495378044884426</lastName>
        <personID>111111111111</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</uuid>
        <firstName>fake first name: 0.8945739434355868</firstName>
        <address>fake address: 0.40784763231471777</address>
        <personID>222222222222</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</uuid>
        <firstName>fake first name: 0.7863207851479257</firstName>
        <lastName>fake last name: 0.09918620445731652</lastName>
        <personID>111111111111</personID>
    </Person>

    <MoreStuff>
        <foo></foo>
        <foo>fooo</foo>
        <foo><bar></bar></foo>
        <foo>
            <bar></bar>
            <bar></bar>
            <bar>bb</bar>
        </foo>
        <bar></bar>
    </MoreStuff>

</ADocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if an XSLT can help out here.  Perhaps my knowledge on XSLT is not profound enough, but an XSLT is used create a new XML structure based on the data of an existing XML.  It seems like you want to do the opposite here: maintaining the same structure but updateing the data based on dynamic values.  You might have a hard time creating such an XSLT.
The optimalisation can depend on quite some parameters: the number of Person elements per XML, the amound of equal PersonIds in the XML, the number of XMLs to treat, ...  If you re dealing with large files you might want to switch to a SAX implementation to optimize your memory consumption.  If you re dealign with a large number of equal PersonIDs in the same XML you can build some caching structure behind your fake data which you use to replace in order to reduce the amount of hits on your DOM (you can directly replace the node with the cached node and overwrite the uuid with the original one).
If you have alot of small files containing similar PersonIDs you might want to use cross XML caching if it is acceptable that the same fake data can be used over multiple XML files.

Also, I believe you can drop the 'setIfExists' on the PersonID as it is stated as a mandatory field.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the relative performance but here is an XSLT solution to your problem.

The following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- Find the position of the first Person with the same personID as this Person. 
       This will be used to provide a unique identifier for that person. -->
  <xsl:template name="get-position-id">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(../../Person[personID=current()/../personID][1]/preceding-sibling::Person)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For personID elements, we will replace the number with a number based on the position of 
       the first Person with the same personId. -->
  <xsl:template match="personID">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="position-id">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-position-id"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="create-person-id">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$position-id"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For elements that match this template, we will replace the text with an arbitrary string
       appended with a number linking them to a particular personID. -->
  <xsl:template match="firstName|lastName|address">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="position-id">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-position-id"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="create-fake-string">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$position-id"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This template generates a number that can be used to replace personID. -->
  <xsl:template name="create-person-id">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <!-- Turn the input into a 12-digit number padded by zeroes. -->
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($input, '000000000000') "/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This template generates a string that can be used to replace data. -->
  <xsl:template name="create-fake-string">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <!-- Create a string to replace data with, appending the input parameter. -->
    <xsl:text>FAKEDATA</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following XML when applied to your example document:

```
<ADocument>
  <Stuff>
    ...
  </Stuff>
  <OtherStuff>
    ...
  </OtherStuff>
  <Person>
    <uuid>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</uuid>
    <firstName>FAKEDATA0</firstName>
    <lastName>FAKEDATA0</lastName>
    <personID>000000000000</personID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <uuid>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</uuid>
    <firstName>FAKEDATA1</firstName>
    <address>FAKEDATA1</address>
    <personID>000000000001</personID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <uuid>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</uuid>
    <firstName>FAKEDATA0</firstName>
    <lastName>FAKEDATA0</lastName>
    <personID>000000000000</personID>
  </Person>
  <MoreStuff>
    ...
  </MoreStuff>
</ADocument>
```